# Whether Internal source resistance will have effect on the circuit

Tags: bjt, resistance, source

[image: Ckt Diagram]

Calculate the voltage gain for the network of Fig. 3.12 if the source has an internal
resistance of 100  in series with Vi.Vi=500mV,R= 1K ?

For this problem I had tried a solution but I am not sure whether it is correct or not?
Please Help.
Below is the solution that i have found

Ii = Vi/Ri = 25mA
For this ckt, Ie=Ii=25mA

Since, Ic is approx equal to Ie, Ic=25mA
VL=Ic*R=25V
Hence, Av=Vl/Vi=50.

Is my solution correct?
I am assuming that the internal resistance of source will not have any effect on the circuit.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The 'key' point is, how the gain is defined? That is, which is the 'input' and which is the 'output'?

Answer (score 1):

From the given input resistance \$r_{i}=20\;Ohms\$ I deduce that the transconductance is **\$g_{m}=\frac{1}{r_{i}}=0.05A/V\$**. Because of

$$
I_{c}=g_{m} \times V_{t} \quad(V_{t}=temeperature\: voltage, V_{t}=25mV)
$$

we can calculate the DC current **\$I_{c}=I_{e}=0.05 \times 25 mA=1.25 mA\$** (neglecting \$I_{b}\$).

The voltage gain referred to the base node is **\$A_{1}=g_{m} \times (r_{o}||R_{L})\$** and the gain referred to the signal source (with internal \$R_{s}=100\;ohms\$) is **\$A_{0}=A_{1} \times r_{i}/(r_{i}+R_{s})\$**.

For an input signal of Vi=0.5 V the resulting signal ouput is app. 4V.